# xcode A device with number already exists on this team.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I recently renew my iOS development program with apple. since then I can not run my new projects on my devices. If I go to organizer inside xCode I can see the devices and they have the green light next to the device. If I load any of my old projects I can run the project on the devices with no problem.

I have try to remove the device and adding the device again but when I add it again I get this error:

A device with number 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' already exists on this team.

my question to guys is what in the world can I do the fix this issue and be able to run new projects on my devices? any suggestions ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: have you implemented code sign ident. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had the same issue today, and I solved that with deleting all the provisioning profiles from the device, unplugged the device and then plug in again.

I downloaded the TeamProvisionigProfile manually from the apple developer site. After that I add the "TeamProvisioningProfile" manually through the Organizer.

This works for me to install the application again. Hopefully it works for you too!?