# Got new iPhone, can't add as a device to develop on

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I plug my iPhone 5 in, Xcode recognizes it, but when I build my code and try to run it on my phone, I get this error:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

So I go to the organizer, click the phone under Devices and click Add to Portal, but I get this error:

> A device with number '...' already exists on this team.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873396/xcode-a-device-with-number-already-exists-on-this-team

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added it to the portal but did you add that device into your provisioning profile for your app as well? I would check to make sure that the device is actually listed in the prov profile and that you've downloaded & installed it. I'd also kill the previous copy of the prov profile out of Organizer. Also, sometimes XCode goes brain dead with device additions and will need a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem earlier today.

Firstly check that you have a valid key pair for the provisioning profile you're trying to use.
Then reissue your certificate using a new certificate generation request. Create a new provisioning profile using your new key pair and set that manually rather than using the organiser in XCode.